# Не могу установить pyinstaller python 3.11 ubuntu

Tags: python

Когда устанавливаю через `pip`, выдает такую ошибку:
`error: externally-managed-environment`

Когда устанавливаю через `sudo apt`, выдает такую ошибку:
`E: Unable to locate package pyinstaller`

Еще многое пробовал -- не помогает.

Comment: Создайте виртуальное окружение (virtualenv) и работайте внутри него

Comment: Спасибо!!! Сейчас попробую этот вариант.

Comment: не помогло и это тоже

Comment: Что значит «не помогло»?

Comment: Разобрался). Не туда пакеты устанавливал оказывается. Спасибо еще раз!!!